Whats is a word to describe a (non-food) product that has an expiry date in a technical/system documentation context?
I'm currently writing up documentation for an internal computing system that manages medical products. These products have a shelf-life or expiry date that is set by the manufacturer but they tend not to be actually perishable (e.g. suture thread) - normally because the sterile packaging will eventually be compromised (and also to ensure a steady stream of orders, if I'm being cynical).
I hesitate to use the 'perishable' for this reason but I can't think of another appropriate word. This is in an Australian context.

What’s wrong with expiry date? Compounds change or decay at various rates.

As a simple use: "A key benefit of this system will be the management of [perishable] stock items, including the identification of those items nearing the end of their validity period"

You can probably use “obsolete”
not in use any more, having been replaced by something newer and better or more fashionable

You could describe the products as "products with a shelf life" instead of using an adjective.

Perish doesn't imply food.

They are expiration management items.

If you're looking for a technical term, it would probably be better to ask in an industry-specific forum.

@StuartF - Perish the thought!

expirable
